# How to get the third month of a query without using variables?

Tags: sql

I have a query in which I need to get the third month of the given reporting date using SQL and then use it as part of the query. I am able to get all the months but I specifically need to get the third month how would I go about doing that? I know this is fairly easy to do in other languages but is it possible in SQL?

```
SELECT REPORTING_MONTH, COUNT(*)
FROM database1 AS fb
    JOIN (
        --derrived core set
        SELECT service_no, subscription_id
        FROM database2 
        WHERE REPORTING_MONTH = '2015-04-01' <-- this is the reporting month
    ) AS c
    ON fb.SERVICE_NO = c.service_no
    AND fb.subscription_id = c.subscription_id
    AND fb.REPORTING_MONTH = '2015-07-01' <-- THIS SHOULD BE THE THIRD MONTH
    AND fb.ACTIVE_BASE_IND_NEW = 1
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

For example if the reporting month is '2015-04-01 I need the variable month to then be '2015-07-01' to be used as part of the query

Comment: Have you tried using `DATEADD (month , 3 , c.REPORTING_MONTH )` ?

Comment: I removed the conflicting database tags.  With your reputation, you should know how to tag a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't specify the database you are using.  A typical approach would be:

```
SELECT REPORTING_MONTH, COUNT(*)
FROM database1 fb JOIN
     database2 c
     ON fb.SERVICE_NO = c.service_no AND
        c.REPORTING_MONTH = '2015-04-01' AND
        fb.subscription_id = c.subscription_id AND
        fb.REPORTING_MONTH = c.reporting_month + interval '3 month' AND
        fb.ACTIVE_BASE_IND_NEW = 1
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

The exact syntax for `+ interval '3 month'` varies by database.

Answer (score 0):

If the field REPORTING_MONTH is text then you might have to use `SUBSTRING` (SQL Server) or `MID` (Others).

If it's a proper date field then perhaps `DATEPART(month, fb.REPORTING_MONTH) = 3` will work?

My SQL is a bit rusty but try those functions.